# Rotate a 3D triangle to another one

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

Suppose that I have two 3D triangles sharing an edge, as shown by the picture below.

[image: Two_Triangle]

The Two triangles, i.e. $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta BCD$ share the edge $BC$. The coordinates of nodes $A, B, C$ and $D$ are known.

Now, I want to rotate $\Delta ABC$ to $\Delta BCD$ around $BC$, making the two triangles partially overlapping (because two triangles are different).

By the way, I have to make sure that, after rotation, the two triangles partially overlap, instead of being adjacent on the same 3D plane.

The quaternion might be a solution, but I kind of dislike it, because the direction of rotation axis could affect the result, i.e. $BC$ or $CB$. Also, to use the quaternion rotation, the angle between the two triangles is required.

Is there any sound solution just based on the node coordinates?

Comment: The quaternion is just a representation of the rotation.  Any ambiguity in your problem is independent of the representation.  The most intuative is the axis-angle representation.  You know the axis, you just have to determine the angle.  You can do this with vector math.  Use cross product to get two vectors in the plane and then use dot product to get the angle.

Comment: Can you give more details about the overlapping ?  How is that specified in terms of coordinates ?  For example, is the final image of $\triangle ABC$ which is overlapping with $\triangle ABD$ given ?  If not, then how are supposed to know where the rotated triangle $ABC$ will be after rotation ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the axis to be

$\vec v = (C-B)$

then you can define a vector in the plane of $\Delta ABC$ as

$\vec a = \vec v \times \left( (A-B)\times \vec v \right)$

likewise for $\Delta ADC$

$\vec d = \vec v \times \left( (D-B)\times \vec v \right)$

Then the angle between them would be

$\theta = \cos^-1 \left( \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec d}{| \vec a |\cdot | \vec d|} \right)$

this represents the rotation in terms of the axis $\vec v$ and the angle $\theta$.

You can then use documentation on the axis-angle representation to convert to a rotation matrix using this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation

Once you have the rotation matrix $R$ you can transform the point $A$ with

$A' = R(A-B) + B$

Note that there are cleaner ways to do this but this is the most intuative.

Comment: Excellent way! $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{d}$ are two 3D vectors on the two triangles, respectively, and both are perpendicular to $BC$ but are in the direction of away-from-$BC$.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what they are.